# Visual Studio 2013 or 2015 colors

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, colors

Is it possible to change the color of a tab in Visual Studio 2013/2015 so it is a different color if it's not part of your active solution?  If so, how?  I looked through the color settings and didn't see anything that jumped out at me, so I'm guessing it's not an option but I figured I'd cast a net to the community and see if anybody's actually done it or knows about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install Productivity Power Tools 2013\2015 and use **Tab Behavior & Tab UI** features to control the color's of a tab.

The Tab Behavior feature allows to sort tabs by project
Tabs will be sorted by the project they belong to, thus keeping them always together in the document tab well.

In addition, the **Tab UI** feature, colors tabs according to their project or according to regular expressions.
This option permits tabs to be colored according to the project they belong to. This is particularly useful when sorting tabs by project, as it allows you to immediately identify different groups of project documents.
You can also configure regular expressions and assign a color to each one. If the name of a tab matches the configured regular expression, it will be colored with the assigned color.

Download link:

[Productivity Power Tools 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace)

[Productivity Power Tools 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d)

I hope it supports your questions.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are looking for: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace

Comment: Selected the other answer because it included VS 2015 info as well as 2013, and more details